# adding temporary static routes to Ubuntu router

Tags: networking

i usually create permanent static routes and i wanted to know how to make temporary ones (i want them to delete within reboot).
i found some ways here on the website but from some reason they didn't work for me (i'm not working with Ubuntu usually)

would appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `ip route` to add routes on the fly.

Example :

```
sudo ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.1.254 # Specific route
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 # Default route (gw)
```

This is not persistent.