# How to add routes

Tags: routing

In windows I add to the routing table:

> route add  159.182.151.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 159.182.152.110

How to add similar to ubuntu ?

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding temporary static routes to Ubuntu router](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054097/adding-temporary-static-routes-to-ubuntu-router)

Comment: `sudo ip route add 159.182.151.0/24 via 159.182.152.110`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo route add -net 159.182.151.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 159.182.152.110
```