# Disable VPN for certain local devices, such as an embedded Linux board I need to ssh into (Allow local (LAN) access when using VPN)

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, ip

I have the Cisco Annyconnect VPN on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I also have an embedded Linux board plugged in that I need to connect to over ssh.

Whenever I connect to my VPN, however, I can no longer talk to my local board (`ping 10.1.2.3` fails with the VPN connected, as does `ssh root@10.1.2.3`). How can I disable the VPN for this board only, so that the interface talking to this local board does *not* go through the VPN?

Example info:

1. My main Ubuntu machine:

   1. Interface name for the interface connecting to this local Linux board (as shown by `ifconfig`): `enxf8e43b9df776`
   2. Static IP to the local Linux board: `10.1.2.1`
   3. Netmask: `255.255.255.0`
2. Local embedded Linux board which I need to ssh into:

   1. Static IP address: `10.1.2.3`
   2. Netmask: `255.255.255.0`

This doesn't work for me: [Is it possible to stop using VPN on some application?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1131049/327339)

I need to be able to use the VPN to connect to some remote networks while simultaneously using my *local* embedded Linux board.

### Possibly useful:

1. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/70847-local-lan-pix-asa.html

   1. `grep -rn 'LocalLanAccess' /opt/cisco`
   2. `grep -rn '<AnyConnectProfile' /opt/cisco`
2. I need to try this out; this is quite the hack!--building a custom function, C++ name-mangling and all!--and preloading it at the library load time to override the internal function by that name: [Super User: How to allow local LAN access while connected to Cisco VPN?](https://superuser.com/a/546668/425838)
3. OpenConnect - an alternative to try, which is apparently compatible with Cisco AnyConnect

   1. https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect
   2. http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/

Here are some things I did which did *not* prove to solve the problem or be useful (at least not yet, anyway):

```bash
grep -rn 'LocalLanAccess' /opt/cisco


$ grep -rn 'LocalLanAccess' /opt/cisco
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/.anyconnect_global:15:<LocalLanAccess>false</LocalLanAccess></ControllablePreferences>
Binary file /opt/cisco/anyconnect/lib/libvpnapi.so matches
Binary file /opt/cisco/anyconnect/lib/libvpnagentutilities.so matches
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/vpn_profile.xml:15:       <LocalLanAccess UserControllable="true">false</LocalLanAccess>
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/AnyConnectProfile.xsd:325:            <xs:element name="LocalLanAccess" default="false" minOccurs="0">


cp -i /opt/cisco/anyconnect/.anyconnect_global /opt/cisco/anyconnect/.anyconnect_global.bak
cp -i /opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/vpn_profile.xml /opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/vpn_profile.xml.bak
cp -i /opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/AnyConnectProfile.xsd /opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/AnyConnectProfile.xsd.bak


# manually update all 3 files to true

$ grep -rn 'LocalLanAccess' /opt/cisco
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/.anyconnect_global:15:<LocalLanAccess>true</LocalLanAccess></ControllablePreferences>
Binary file /opt/cisco/anyconnect/lib/libvpnapi.so matches
Binary file /opt/cisco/anyconnect/lib/libvpnagentutilities.so matches
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/vpn_profile.xml:15:       <LocalLanAccess UserControllable="true">true</LocalLanAccess>
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/AnyConnectProfile.xsd:325:            <xs:element name="LocalLanAccess" default="true" minOccurs="0">
```

Comment: This is something you need to ask the Cisco VPN people about. I use ExpressVPN and their product is an all or nothing. I have to stop the VPN to use ssh even internal. It "protects" the machine completely.

Comment: What's the output of `ip route -n` before and after connecting to the VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Use `openconnect` via the `openconnect-sso` wrapper instead! Cisco AnyConnect intentionally blocks LAN access.

Basic usage of `openconnect-sso`:

```bash
VPN_SERVER_ADDRESS="myvpn.whatever.com"   # example server address to connect to
VPN_SAML_GROUP="whatever-saml-whatever"   # example SAML group name
VPN_USER="my.username@something.com"      # example username
# or perhaps just this for the username:
# VPN_USER="my.username"

# connect via `openconnect-sso`
# The first time ever, you must specify everything
openconnect-sso --server "${VPN_SERVER_ADDRESS}/${VPN_SAML_GROUP}" --user "${VPN_USER}"
# Subsequent connection attempts can be done with just this, since apparently
# the server address, SAML group, and username are cached after the first usage
openconnect-sso
```

For **full details, screenshots, and installation instructions**, see my answer here: [How to use "openconnect" (via the `openconnect-sso` wrapper) with SAML and Duo two-factor authentication via Okta Single-Sign-on (SSO)](https://superuser.com/a/1753172/425838)